# #ifdef within a #ifdef

Tags: c, macros

In the C excerpt below, is SUPPORT_MULTI_DNS_SERVER executed only when ProductName is defined?

```
#ifdef <ProductName>
 //do things here
#ifdef SUPPORT_MULTI_DNS_SERVER
 //do things here
#endif
 //do things here
#endif
```

Edit: SWE780 changed to product name.

Comment: There is no `SWE780` in the code you show. The code inside the inner `#ifdef` (the second one) is kept in the program if and only of both the outer (first) `#ifdef` and the inner `#ifdef` are satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is how conditional inclusions work. The `ifdef` nested within another `ifdef` is included only if the first `ifdef` evaluates to true. In your case:

```
#ifdef SUPPORT_MULTI_DNS_SERVER
 //do things here
#endif
```

is included only if `#ifdef <ProductName>` is true (I am assuming `<ProductName>` is SWE780).

From the C Committee draft (N1570):

> **6.10.1 Conditional inclusion**
>   ...
>
> 6. **Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group that it controls is skipped:** directives are processed only through the name that determines the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals; the rest of the directives’ preprocessing tokens are ignored, as are the other preprocessing tokens in the
>      group. Only the first group whose control condition evaluates to true (nonzero) is processed. If none of the conditions evaluates to true, and there is a `#else` directive, the group controlled by the `#else` is processed; lacking a #else directive, all the groups until the `#endif` are skipped.

Comment: Just to clarify, can a #ifdef be left hanging without a #endif? Like in a regular if-else statements, curly bracket is not neccessary if it's just a line.

Comment: No, this is not possible. Each #ifdef should have a corresponding #endif. Otherwise there will be a compilation error stating, `error: unterminated #ifdef`

Answer (score 4):

Pre-processor conditionals will nest. For example, with:

```
#ifdef XYZZY
    int a;
    #ifdef PLUGH
        int b;
    #endif
    int c;
#endif
```

The `b` variable will exist only if *both* `XYZZY` and `PLUGH` are defined. The `a` and `c` variables depend only on `XYZZY`.

From the C11 standard, section `6.10.1 Conditional inclusion /6`:

> Each directive’s condition is checked in order. If it evaluates to false (zero), the group that it controls is skipped: directives are processed *only* through the name that determines the directive in order to keep track of the level of nested conditionals.

This "group" is the entire section, including all sub-groups. In the example given above, the `XYZZY` group is *everything* between `#ifdef XYZZY` and the corresponding `#endif`.